# How to set WPF app to always be inactive so it does not steal focus from other apps

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

What I want:

Set my WPF to inactive all the time, even when I press buttons, whatever I do with that WPF app as I'm interacting with it, I don't want any other app to lose it's focus/activation, for example, how does a software keyboard work? if the keyboard is to input text correctly, the active window (google for example) has to remain active while the software keyboard is being used, otherwise the keyboard would not be able to input keystrokes since google lost focus/activation when the keyboard is touched.

What I want to do:

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("1");

}
```

My WPF needs to send that keystroke text into the active window of 'google' for example, but when I press the button the focus/activation from google is lost and it is now in my WPF app, due to this I could not send the keystroke, just imagine the surface pro 3 software keyboard, when you press it's buttons it does not take away the current applications focus/activation, I want to do something similar, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it possible because you just focus a window on click.
You could unfocus the mainwindow all the time when it got focused.

```
 public partial class App : Application
  {
    public App()
    {      
       Activated += (s,e) => 
       {
          App.Current.MainWindow.SetValue(MyApp.MainWindow.IsFocusedProperty, false);
       };
    }   
  }
```

Comment: i dont know how to put this in my code, i keep getting different exceptions/errors